# search in the first 300 rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio R2

suppose I have a table tableX with infinite records count,
and that table has a column colX, and the there's only 2 records in the whole table that have this colX not null,

what should the query look like?

I used

```
select top 10 * from tableX where colX isnot null
```

but it took forever executing the query

it there a way to search in the first 300 rows only?
thanks

Comment: Do you already have an index on colX?

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Searching the entire resultset is to slow so you ask how to search only 300 records. You *should* be asking why the initial search is to slow to begin with... *(@MarkBannister's suggestion would be a good start)*.

Comment: This may be minor but it might help if you were more precise in your description. Otherwise, if we are to take your words literally, I'd say "forever" correlates rather well with the "infinite records count".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks for your help, I fixed this problem in a tricky way,

I did make a new table

```
Declare tempTable table(...columns...)
```

and then

```
insert into tempTable (select top 300* from tableX)
```

after that,

```
select * from tempTable where colX is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to search in the first 300 rows only?

Yes, there is:

```
select top 300 * from tableX where colX isnot null order by id asc
```

This assumes you have a column called id on tableX and it's an identity column. Basically, we probably need more info. :-)

Comment: this keeps the problem occuring my friend, seems the problem is that SQL gets all the records then it filters, I want to search only in the first 300 records. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ok, but your solution doesn't need to use a temp table: select * from tableX where colX is not null and id in (select top 300 id from tableX).

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. I used

```
query.setMaxResults(300)
```

It is the same as LIMIT in SQL but worked for me from Java code.